# Can a UICollectionView scroll vertically with a columnar layout?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am building  UICollectionView that needs to scroll vertically, but lay out its items in a columnar format in order to handle varying item heights, like this:

[image]

A column-by-column layout is the default for a horizontally-scrolling collection view, but mine needs to scroll vertically.  What's the easiest way to accomplish this?  Do I need to subclass UICollectionViewLayout, or can UICollectionViewFlowLayout do it?  Or...?

Comment: You can achieve it using subclassing the UICollectionViewLayout

Comment: There are tons of third party controls available that layout UICollectionView items the you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a subclass of UICollectionViewLayout called [SelfSizingWaterfallCollectionViewLayout](https://github.com/adamwaite/SelfSizingWaterfallCollectionViewLayout) on GitHub that does exactly what I needed.